# Best ways of retrieving strings based on parsed integer code?

Tags: c, string

Please ignore the topic of the post as it may sound something else instead of what I am actually asking here.

I want to make a C function which should retrieve me a string value associated with a specific integer code whose signature will be something very simple like:

```
char *Get_Msg (int code, char *errorInfoTable[][2]);
```

So, I need the strings as well associated codes stored first and because I cannot take an array of multiple datatypes, I end up storing the codes also in terms of strings as:

```
char *errorInfo[][2] = {

/* Error Code  Error Message
 * ----------  ------------- */
   {      "0", "No error"                                  },
   {     "93", "Error in processing"                       },
   { "-32700", "PARSE_ERROR"                               },
   { "-32600", "INVALID_REQUEST "                          },  
};
```

Then I may just read this table in the function which in turn should return me the associated string. Firstly, is it a good way to define this table inside that function itself or as a global variable in the file. But what if I wish to store this functionality in a separate C file and call it from some other file. I see that if I declare the file as a global variable, I need to declare an extern for **char *errorInfoTable[][2]** in the main file and the function and then parse in the function. I want the code to calculate the number of rows in the parsed table itself. This does not seem to work if I try to calculate the number of rows withing the **Get_Msg** function as the function cannot see it from the formal parameter **char *errorInfoTable[][2]**. I can do this by mentioning the number of rows in the formal parameter or passing the number of rows as well in the function but I don't want to calculate the number of rows explicitly anywhere. I want to design it in such a way that the programmer will just add/delete the number of rows in the table and should not touch any dimensions anywhere else in the program.

Is there any other way you to store and retrieve strings from this table? or any other better ways for this functionality?

Comment: You can make an array of structures... the members of which can be of varying data types...

Comment: create a structure instead

Answer (score 4):

```
struct { int error_code; const char *message; } errorInfo[] = {

/* Error Code  Error Message
 * ----------  ------------- */
   { -32700, "PARSE_ERROR"                               },
   { -32600, "INVALID_REQUEST "                          },  
   {      0, "No error"                                  },
   {     93, "Error in processing"                       },
};
```

That should give you what you want. And keeping it sorted can even allow you to do logarithmic lookup.
I'd also keep the table static and inside `Get_Msg`.

If you need to store more data relating to the code, you would do something like this:

```
struct error_code_data {
  int error_code;
  const char *message;
  /* More data */
};

struct error_code_data const * get_error_code_data(int error_code);
```

Comment: In other words, `typedef` this struct then have the function returning one such struct item. The table of structs should be `const` and indeed declared inside the function.

Comment: @Lundin, that's not in other words, that's something completely different. For the purpose of simple quick and dirty error code to string translation, I won't add an entirely new named struct. If there is more data to be stored relating to the code, I'd return `struct error_code_data *`, since I'm of the Linus Torvalds schools of thought when it comes to handling big struct definitions and typedefing the `struct` away.

Comment: Thanks, this sounds really perfect. You said "I'd also keep the table static and inside Get_Msg", so this will mean no multiple allocations will be done for the table (during multiple calls of the function) and it will stay alive till the end of the program. Right?

Comment: @AbhishekKumar, yes pretty much. static data is alive for the duration of the program. And keeping in the function reduces coupling.

Comment: @StoryTeller Eh, return a pointer? To what? Dynamically allocated hard-copy? Non-const pointer to const struct?

Comment: @AbhishekKumar Making the table `static` doesn't make much sense if it is already a local `const`. There will be no multiple allocations of any `const` variable. It will end up in the .rodata segment no matter if it is static or not.

Comment: @Lundin, yes you are correct. I was too eager to type to be const correct, I'm afraid.

Comment: Don't be so eager! :) The extra const you added to make the returned pointer read-only actually just applies to the temporary pointer object returned from the function. So it fills no purpose, better to just do `struct error_code_data const *`.

Comment: @Lundin Concerning `static const` inside a function that "doesn't make much sense", the C11 spec §7.27.3.1 2 does that.  I see nothing in the spec about _.rodata segment_.

Comment: @chux Citing the often blatantly irrational C standard as a counter-example to "doesn't make sense" isn't the best idea... :) That being said, `static const` with an explicit storage specifier could perhaps be considered as the most formal way to declare such a variable. Similar to `auto signed int i` instead of `int i` or `extern void func (void);` instead of `void func (void)`. It won't affect the generated code. And then of course, the C standard knows very little of things like computers, memories and memory segments.